# Spring cloud sleuth Annotations: Autowiring doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have Spring cloud sleuth(and also zipkin) configured in my application. I have a controller which calls service, which in turn calls repository and finally database.

The setup works fine, Sleuth is generating span id's and It is visible in zipkin as well. I wanted to try creating span's across multiple internal beans and methods. I came across [Managing Spans with Annotations](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#managing-spans-with-annotations). This does not seem to work.

When I use any of the annotations mentioned here like `@NewSpan` or `@ContinueSpan`, Autowiring stops working. My service class which is autowired in Controller is `null`. If I remove these annotations everything works again.

I am using.

`spring-boot 2.2.5.RELEASE`

`spring-cloud.version Hoxton.SR3`
I have these dependencies in my pom

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId> // This is pulling 2.2.2.RELEASE version
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Here is a sample code

```
@RestController
class SomeController {

@Autowired
SomeService someService;

    @GetMapping("/init")
    @NewSpan("init")
    private void init()  {
        someService.init();
    }
}
```

And my Service class is like

```
@Service
Class SomeService {
  .....

   @ContinueSpan(log = "init")
    public void init() {

    }
}
```

My guess is, Spring-Aop has something to do with it. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? Which version of Sleuth are you using? How are you using the annotations?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak updated the question with details

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use field injection, use constructor injection. Also new span there doesn't make sense cause you already have a new span created by the framework.

Comment: Doesn't change even If I use contructor Injection. Yes, I removed the annotations from controller and used in my service layer, where I have no issues. Any idea, why it doesn't work in controller?

Comment: Most likely you're inside the proxy and you're trying to use a field that the proxy doesn't have. You could call a method and maybe that would work. Anyways that's not a good idea cause you already have a span there.